# Trouble with tables in Dreamweaver :)

Tags: html, html-table, dreamweaver

I have made complex a page, with tables and phps, in Dreamweaver. The page looks fine in browser, but the tables look messed up when in Dreamweaver.
In code view, it marks this tags as invalid/

```
<?php

if ( !$_COOKIE['user'] ) { die( '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=index.php">Please your enable cookies.' ); }

$database = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'marina', 'art24_database') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$result = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM irnieki WHERE USER_NAME = '".$_COOKIE['user']."' and PASSWORD = '".$_COOKIE['pass']."' " );
if ( !$result ) { die('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=index.php">Invalid username or password.'); }

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Artilerijas 24</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #E7E6E0;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.inputtable {
    background-color: #F5F4F3;
    border: 1px solid #CDCBC7;
}
#apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:148px;
    height:200px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 51px;
    top: 169px;
    background-color: #FF6B09;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #A83200;
    background-image: url(gfx/apdiv.png);
}
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:173px;
    height:74px;
    z-index:1;
    background-image: url(gfx/coffee1.png);
    left: 54px;
    top: 98px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

p.big {
  line-height: 215%;
}




-->
</style></head>

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div id="apDiv2"><b>Skaitītāji
<br><br>
Vēl kaut kas
<br><br>
Un vēl-vēl kaut kas
<br><br>
Te arī kaut kas interesants
</b></div>
<br>
<center><img src="gfx/coffee1.png" width="292" height="72" /></center>
<div id="apDiv1"></div>
<table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="25" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="gfx/frame_ctl.png" width="25" height="51" /></td>
    <td height="25" align="center" valign="top" background='gfx/frame_topbg.png' bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="gfx/frame_top.png" width="400" height="51" /></td>
    <td height="25" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="gfx/frame_ctr.png" width="25" height="51" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25" align="center" background='gfx/frame_left.png' bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><br>
      <br>
      <br>
    <br>
    </td>

    <td width="750" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">    
<!-- MIGHT BE SOMETHING WRONG WITH THE LINE ABOVE! -->




    <?php

    echo 'Laipni lūdzam, '.$row['UZVARDS'].'!';

    $dzivarray = array();

    array_push($dzivarray, 'Nams Artilērijas 24');

    $result = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM irnieki ORDER BY 'ID'" );
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { if ( $row['DZIVOKLIS'] != '' ) { $dzivarray[$row['DZIVOKLIS']] = $row['DZIVOKLIS']; }}






    if ( isset($_POST['submitrad']) ) {

        if ( $_POST['karstuddziv'] != '' && $_POST['aukstuddziv'] != '' ) {
mysqli_query($database, "INSERT INTO dynamic (DATE,DZIVOKLIS,UDENS_AUKST,UDENS_KARST)
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['newdate']."','".$_POST['dziv']."','".$_POST['aukstuddziv']."','".$_POST['karstuddziv']."')" );
        $status = '<font color = "#00CC00"> SAGLABĀTS.</font>';

        } else { $status = '<font color = "#FF0000">NAV SAGLABĀTS, RĀDĪJUMS NAV IEVADĪTS.</font>'; }

        }





    ?>

<br><br><br><br><br>





<table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
<td><font color="#595454">Lūdzu ievadiet rādījumus: </font></td></tr></table><br>
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="inputtable"><tr>
<td height="120" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F5F4F3">
<form name=formdziv action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td width="26%" align="center" valign="middle">Dzīvoklis<br /><br />
<select name="selectdziv" id="selectdziv" onchange=" formdziv.submit(); " >


<?php  foreach ($dzivarray as $x ) {

$result = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM irnieki WHERE DZIVOKLIS = '".$x."' " );
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$name = $row['UZVARDS'];

    echo '<option ';
    if ( $x == $_POST['selectdziv'] ) { echo 'selected'; }
    echo ' value = "'.$x.'" >'.$x.' - '.$name.'</option>' ; }

echo '</select>';


if ( $_POST['selectdziv'] == 'Nams Artilērijas 24' || $_POST['selectdziv'] == '' ) { echo'<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>'; }

?>

</td><td width="49%" align="right" valign="middle">
<!-- MIGHT BE SOMETHING WRONG WITH THE LINE ABOVE! -->

<?php

if ( $_POST['selectdziv'] == "Nams Artilērijas 24" || $_POST['selectdziv'] == '' ) {

echo '
<br><br>Ūdens rādīījumi <input name="udrad" type="text" id="textfield" size="11" value="'.$_POST["karstuddziv"].'" /><br>
<br>"Rīgas Ūdens" rēķins (LVL) <input name="udrekins" type="text" id="textfield" size="11" value="'.$_POST["karstuddziv"].'" /><br>
<br>Siltums rādīījumi <input name="udrad" type="text" id="textfield" size="11" value="'.$_POST["karstuddziv"].'" /><br>
<br>"Rīgas Siltums" rēķins (LVL) <input name="siltrekins" type="text" id="textfield" size="11" value="'.$_POST["karstuddziv"].'" /><br>
<br>Elektrības rādījum <input name="elrad" type="text" id="textfield2" size="11" value="'.$_POST["aukstuddziv"].'" /><br><br><br><br><br>';

} else {

echo'
<br>Karstais Ūdens <input name="karstuddziv" type="text" id="textfield" size="11" value="'.$_POST["karstuddziv"].'" /><br>
<br>Aukstais Ūdens <input name="aukstuddziv" type="text" id="textfield2" size="11" value="'.$_POST["aukstuddziv"].'" /><br><br>
'; }

?>

</td><td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">
<!-- MIGHT BE SOMETHING WRONG WITH THE LINE ABOVE! -->

<?php
if ( !$_POST['selectdziv'] ) { $dziv = $dzivarray[0]; } else { $dziv = $_POST['selectdziv']; }

    if ( $dziv != "Nams Artilērijas 24" ) {

        $result = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM dynamic WHERE DZIVOKLIS = '$dziv' AND UDENS_AUKST != '' ORDER BY 'ID' ASC" );
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { $newdate = $row['DATE']; }

        if ( $newdate != '' ) {
            $newdate = strtotime(date("d.m.Y.", strtotime($newdate)) . " +1 month");
            $newdate = date("d.m.Y.", $newdate); } else { $newdate = '01.06.2010.'; }

        echo $newdate;

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="newdate" value="'.$newdate.'">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="dziv" value="'.$dziv.'">';

        } else {



        $result = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM dynamic WHERE UDENS_RAD != '' ORDER BY 'ID' ASC" );
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { $newdate = $row['DATE']; }
        if ( $newdate != '' ) {
            $newdate = strtotime(date("d.m.Y.", strtotime($newdate)) . " +1 month");
            $newdate = date("d.m.Y.", $newdate); } else { $newdate = '01.06.2010.'; }
        echo '<br><p class="big">'.$newdate.'';     

        $result = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM dynamic WHERE UDENS_RAD != '' ORDER BY 'ID' ASC" );
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { $newdate = $row['DATE']; }
        if ( $newdate != '' ) {
            $newdate = strtotime(date("d.m.Y.", strtotime($newdate)) . " +1 month");
            $newdate = date("d.m.Y.", $newdate); } else { $newdate = '01.06.2010.'; }
        echo '<p class="big">'.$newdate.'';             

        $result = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM dynamic WHERE UDENS_RAD != '' ORDER BY 'ID' ASC" );
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { $newdate = $row['DATE']; }
        if ( $newdate != '' ) {
            $newdate = strtotime(date("d.m.Y.", strtotime($newdate)) . " +1 month");
            $newdate = date("d.m.Y.", $newdate); } else { $newdate = '01.06.2010.'; }
        echo '<p class="big">'.$newdate.'';             

        $result = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM dynamic WHERE UDENS_RAD != '' ORDER BY 'ID' ASC" );
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { $newdate = $row['DATE']; }
        if ( $newdate != '' ) {
            $newdate = strtotime(date("d.m.Y.", strtotime($newdate)) . " +1 month");
            $newdate = date("d.m.Y.", $newdate); } else { $newdate = '01.06.2010.'; }
        echo '<p class="big">'.$newdate.'';             

        $result = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM dynamic WHERE UDENS_RAD != '' ORDER BY 'ID' ASC" );
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { $newdate = $row['DATE']; }
        if ( $newdate != '' ) {
            $newdate = strtotime(date("d.m.Y.", strtotime($newdate)) . " +1 month");
            $newdate = date("d.m.Y.", $newdate); } else { $newdate = '01.06.2010.'; }
        echo '<p class="big">'.$newdate;    






        }

?>

<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submitrad" id="button" value="Saglabāt" <?php if ( $status == '<font color = "#00CC00"> SAGLABĀTS.</font>' ) { echo 'disabled'; } ?> /><br>
</td></tr></table></form></td></tr></table><br /><?php echo $status; ?>
<!-- MIGHT BE SOMETHING WRONG WITH THE LINE ABOVE! -->














<br>
<br><br><br><br><br>

    <td width="25" align="center" background='gfx/frame_right.png' bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="gfx/frame_cbl.png" width="25" height="25" /></td>
    <td height="25" align="center" background='gfx/frame_btm.png' bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="gfx/frame_cbr.png" width="25" height="25" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<font color="grey"><center><br>
Namīpašums Artilērijas 24
</center></font>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
</body>
</html>
```

But they do work normally for the browser. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I copied the whole code and marked place where the error might be coming from with `"<!-- MIGHT BE SOMETHING WRONG WITH THE LINE ABOVE! -->"`

Comment: in the second column there is a `<p>` missing, and in the last one a `</p>`

Comment: "The tables look messed up in Dreamweaver" But how does it look in the browser?

Comment: first trouble is dreamweaver itself!!

Comment: It looks fine in browser, the way it should.

Comment: first of all, why do you care what does it look like in Dreamweaver, as long as it is fine in browsers you do not have to worry about rendering quirks in Dreamweaver. 
second, the problem is most likely to poorly formated html code. you have a xhtml transitional doctype for your page, but there is a lot of code in the page that is for a html doctype. Try the validator.w3.org service, to see what is wrong with your output and start fixing the problems... If you give us a live page where we can see the output of the page I could give you more info

Answer (score 1):

Take out the paragraph tags: `</p>` and `<p>` -- if anywhere they should be inside a table element, not around them.  They also appear to be in the wrong order, but that could simply be because you're only showing us one row.

Comment: Hmm... no, I even removed ALL <p> and </p> tags, but its still messed up in DW ( while normal in browser ).

Answer (score 1):

If it appears fine in the browser, it may just be a problem with Dreamweaver.

Have you tried validating the resulting HTML using [one of the w3c validators](http://validator.w3.org/)? That may result in more helpful information.